# What do "undefined offset" and "trying to get property of non-object" notices mean?

Tags: php, warnings

I can see the output that I want to see but there are 2 errors that I can't understand:

```
 Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\dash\handle_dashim.php on line 23
 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\dash\handle_dashim.php on line 23
```

the important part of the code:

```
//move the objects into array.
$dasharr=array();
$i=1;
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($dashim))) { 
    $dasharr[$i]=new dash($row["name"],$row["msg"],$row["msg_date"],$row["votes"]);
    $i++;
}

//checks the object with the most votes.
$numofdash=count($dasharr); 
$mostvotes=$dasharr[$numofdash];
while($numofdash>0){
    if(($mostvotes->votes)<($dasharr[$numofdash-1]->votes)){ //line 23
    $mostvotes=$dasharr[$numofdash-1];
    }
    $numofdash--;
}


echo $mostvotes->name; //I can see the output that I want

?>
```

Comment: Warnings are *not* Errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

Both those notices are referring to the same problem. You start to assign indexes in your `$dasharr` from the index `1` which is a little bit unusual and inconsistent over programming conventions. Then you are doing a backward while loop testing `while($numofdash > 0)` and trying to retrieve `$dasharr[$numofdash-1]` which will be `$dasharr[0]` (the one that you haven't set) when `$numofdash = 1`.

You have two fast solutions to this problem:

- Set your while loop to test for `$numofdash > 1` instead
- Make your `$dasharr` start from `0` (suggested)

**Other adjustments**

If you intend to follow the latter you can easily remove the use of the `$i` variable by just:

```
$dasharr = array();
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($dashim)))
    $dasharr[] = new dash($row["name"], $row["msg"], $row["msg_date"], $row["votes"]);
```

The `$a[] = ...` notations pushes an object to the closest empty index in the array (automatically starting from `0`).

May I also suggest you to use the `for` loop instead of the `while` loop on the last part of your code?

```
$mostvotes = $dasharr[$numofdash];
for ($numofdash = count($dasharr); $numofdash > 0; $numofdash--)
    if(($mostvotes->votes) < ($dasharr[$numofdash-1]->votes))
        $mostvotes = $dasharr[$numofdash-1];
```

Comment: I am new to PHP so I didn't know that. I learn alot from the comments here. thank you.

Comment: with the second solution I had to change the value of $mostvotes to $numofdash-1. because the array strats now from index 0 and the $numofdash returns 3. the loop should start from index 2.

Answer (score 1):

`$i=1` at the top of your file.

So your first row is `$dasharr[$i]` which is `$dasharr[1]` and up. So the first time in your loop at `$dasharr[1-0]` or `$dasharr[0]` will be undefined.

Comment: To escape this problem, I recommend to change `$dasharr[$i]=new dash...` to `$dasharr[] = new dash...` . Then you can remove all `$i` variables.

Comment: when I change it to "while($numofdash>1)"  it works without erros. But now you tell me that I don't need the $i so I will do it. thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

You have: `$dasharr[$numofdash-1]` if `$numofdash` is 1 then you are referencing `$dasharr[0]` which isn't set above in while loop.

Comment: thank you.I fixed the while statement to "while($numofdash>1)" and now it works. thanks alot. :)

Comment: But this is not a solution of your problem. The problem is a bit deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Please, remove `$i` from first 6 lines of code:

```
$dasharr=array();
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($dashim))) { 
    $dasharr[] = new dash($row["name"],$row["msg"],$row["msg_date"],$row["votes"]);
}
```

As all array indexes starting with 0 and you start with 1, your array becomes an associative array. This means, that you should use, for example, `foreach` statement to enumerate it.

If you have, for example 5 rows, you'll have the following $dasharr structure:

```
[1] => dash object,
[2] => dash object,
[3] => dash object,
[4] => dash object,
[5] => dash object
```

As `count($dasherr)` will equal `5`, your code will never reach element with index `5` and in your case you have an error to request element with index `0`.

To escape such problems in the future, use `var_dump()` function for debugging.